# Identifying why data is skewed in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am investigating a Spark SQL job (Spark 1.6.0) that is performing poorly due to badly skewed data across the 200 partitions, most of the data is in 1 partition:
[image: Index,ID,Attempt,Status,Locality Level,Executor ID/Host,Launch Time,Duration,GC Time,Shuffle Read Size/Records]
What I'm wondering is...is there anything in the Spark UI to help me find out more about how the data is partitioned? From looking at this I don't know which columns the dataframe is partitioned on. How can I find that out? (other than looking at the code - I'm wondering if there's anything in the logs and/or UI that could help me)?

Additional details, this is using Spark's dataframe API, Spark version 1.6. Underlying data is stored in parquet format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spark UI and logs will not be terribly helpful for this. Spark uses a [simple hash partitioning](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/Partitioner.scala#L80) algorithm as the default for almost everything. As you can see here this basically recycles the Java `hashCode` method.

I would suggest the following:

- Try to debug by sampling and printing the contents of the RDD or data frame. See if there's obvious issues with the data distribution (ie. low variance or low cardinality) of the key.
- If thats ineffective, you can work back from the logs and UI to figure our how many partitions there are. You can find the `hashCode` of the data using spark and then take the modulus to see what the collision is.

Once you find the source of the collision you can try to a few techniques to remove it:

- See if there's a better key you can use
- See if you can improve the `hashCode` function of the key (the default one in Java isn't that great)
- See if you can process the data in two steps by doing an initial scatter/gather step to force some parallelism and reduce the processing overhead for that one partition. This is probably the trickiest optimization to get right of those mentioned here. Basically, partition the data once using a random number generator to force some initial parallel combining of the data, then push it through again with the natural partitioner to get the final result. This requires that the operation you're applying be transitive and associative. This technique hits the network twice and is therefore very expensive unless the data is really actually that highly skewed.

Comment: "See if there's a better key you can use" At the time of writing I don't know what key is currently being used. I was basically wondering if there's a way of knowing that from the UI or logs. So far I haven't found anything.

Comment: If you can update your question with details of what API & version (Spark SQL, Hive on Spark, Data Frame, Data Set, RDD) you're using as well as some of the underlying details such as file formats you're using as input it will be easier to provide more advice.

Comment: Can you include a code sample or some details about the operations that are producing the skew?

Comment: I can, because we've actually got to the source of the problem :). Source data was retail transactions and many of them were for an unknown customer , hence they all get the same customer identifier, hence the skew. My question still stands though, I wasn't able to determine from the UI how the data was partitioned (e.g. on which columns) and I was wondering if there was a way to determine this without going back to the original code.

Comment: To answer your question: no, there is not a way to do this from the Spark History Server or application UI.